# Only System Administrator can specify WITH LOG option for RAISERROR command

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am migrating DB scheme from SQL on-premise to SQL Azure. Getting an error saying

```
Only System Administrator can specify WITH LOG option for RAISERROR command.

RAISERROR('Its failed.key %s,error:%s',1,1, @dtStr, @ErrMsg) WITH LOG

Is there any provision that wen Can use <b>With LOG</b> in SQL Azure. 

I tried giving permissions to the user in below way but <b>no luck</b>,.
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbmanager', '<UserName>';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'loginmanager', '<UserName>';
```

Help needed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the WITH LOG option of RAISERROR requires sysadmin privileges which you don't get on SQL Azure because it's a shared environment.

I'd suggest replacing with a BEGIN TRY block and write the errors to a database table instead.

Comment: Thanks you Tony.. This helps..!!